# Analyzer plugin not visible

Tags: ros, plugin, diagnostics, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the tutorial on [Analyzers](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostics/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20Diagnostic%20Analyzer#Loading_Plugin) , I am failing at the step "check that our new plugin is visible to pluginlib and the diagnostic_aggregator".
The command rospack plugins --attrib=plugin diagnostic_aggregator only returns the following:

diagnostic_aggregator /opt/ros/noetic/share/diagnostic_aggregator/analyzer_plugins.xml

I have followed every step from the tutorial, including adding addlibrary(...) in the CMakeLists.txt, writing the analyzer_plugin.xml (btw. is there a recommended path / subfolder where to put this file?), exporting the plugin in the package.xml and building the package succesfully.

The tutorial now tells me to double check the dependencies, then the manifest.xml. Does someone have any hints on what could be wrong or missing? What exactly should be checked?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399970/analyzer-plugin-not-visible/) by [labude](https://answers.ros.org/users/103641/labude/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2022-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved, I had some namespacing issues in the xml and yaml files.

---

Originally posted by [labude](https://answers.ros.org/users/103641/labude/) with karma: 98 on 2022-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0